# Can not run Angular 6 script on react 16.4 app

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to develop an Angular script which we can embed on any site using on script tag  but it gives me following error while trying to embed it in react app.
[image]

Here is what it says on line 196 of my Angular bundle.
.
`var c=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],a=c.push.bind(c);c.push=e,c=c.slice();`

please let me know If you need any further info to help me out...

More screenshots after using completly unminified version
[image: webpackJsonP in Angular pollyfills]
[image: webpackJsonP in webpack bootstrap]

So looks like I am having conflict in this 2 setups. I have access with Angular code only.
What should I do?

Comment: the first thing you might want to do is create a non minified version of your script bundle, so you can actually see what function is throwing the error.  As it stands now, there's no way anyone can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: It's super difficult to debug errors in minified files, let alone asking other people to try and guess what your minified error is. Can you provide more context about your issue?

Comment: @Claies You are right. I didnt realize that -_-
I created semi minified version to make it more clear

Comment: @azium I have provided more context now

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 bundles to do respective framework and inject differently